# ECharts - Graph resets itself after zooming in with the cursor

Tags: angular, echarts

When zooming in to ECharts graph, my code calls setOption once to update the graph but when I set a breakpoint inside the setOption method of EChart, it hits the method twice.

In the first call of setOption, the graph is updated successfully. The second call is triggered by ECharts automatically and resets the graph to its state before zooming in.

As per my understanding, if the options are not set correctly the graph will reset itself unless if 'notMerge' input parameter of 'setOption' is set to true.

Below is the options of the graph when it is first loaded:

[Initial graph settings](https://justpaste.it/de8vp)

And the following is the options when zoomed in (stays for a second or two before the graph resets itself):

[Graph options after zooming in](https://justpaste.it/43jnv)

What could be the reason ECharts is calling 'setOption' with the original options by itself? The options seems to have no missing details to cause the graph to reset unless I am missing something. Your guidance is appreciated

Comment: It's rather difficult to navigate the huge option objects you posted. Running a `diff` I saw that in the new configuration you have `tooltip` and `title` as arrays, while they should be objects. Still, I'm not sure that this would result in the effect you describe. I'd recommend to keep eliminating parts of the argument of  the `setOption` call  until you find the culprit. And if you don't find it, post here a simplified runnable version of your code, which would be much more interesting.